# AngularJS - Run custom directive after ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've a scenario which I want to run a custom directive on the DOM that `ng-bind-html`create.

Basicly I've to customize the behavior of the html tag `<a>` because the html that is loading is unsafe and when the user click the link I've to execute some functions before anything happens, aka, the `click` event of jqLite.

So my original ideia was create a directive that modifies the behavior of any `<a>` inside the container that I put the attribute of my directive.

This works fine, until I combine with `ng-bind-html`, my directive runs before the `ng-bind-html` compile the string into html and attached to the DOM.

So, is any way to run my custom directive after the `ng-bind-html` run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cnU4Z/4/)**

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <div ng-bind="sometext" my-directive>before</div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {   
   $scope.sometext="stuff here";
});
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() { 
        return {
            priority: 10, // adjust this value ;)
            link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngBind, function(newvalue) {
                  console.log("element ",element.text());
                });           
            }
        };      
    });
```

Use `priority` property inside directive to run your code after mg-bind

Comment: Humm.. I didn't think about the `$watch` function.... I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/az7uukk6/1/) fiddle. Other thing I was thinking about is.. I need take care about unbinding the `click` event on the `$destroy` of the scope?

Comment: The Angular documentation for scope destroy, implies that you do need remove DOM events.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$destroy